# Python3 tk TreeView dynamic column width

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Relevant code is below. I am looking for a way to dynamically size a ttk TreeView widget's column to fit the text inside it. I currently have a TreeView (within a class) with minwidths on all the columns, however the text to fill the "notes" column could be infinitely long and the column needs to resize to take that string. I will eventually limit the max size but needless to say I still want it to be dynamic to hold a large string of text if needed but also be neat when the string is shorter.

There are two solutions really, either a dynamic sizing or calculating the pixel width required for a given string, font.measure() is mentioned but this doesn't seem applicable for python 3.x

Any help would be great, I'd like to get this tiny thing sorted so I can finish up!

```
 with sql.connect(dbFile) as dbConnection:
        cursor = dbConnection.cursor()
        self.treeStudentLog = ttk.Treeview(self.mainFrame, columns=("type","points", "notes"), height=21)

        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient='vertical', command=self.treeStudentLog.yview)
        xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient='horizontal', command=self.treeStudentLog.xview)

        yscrollbar.place(x=822, y=240, height=440)
        xscrollbar.place(x=10, y=678, width=813)

        self.treeStudentLog.configure(yscroll=yscrollbar.set, xscroll=xscrollbar.set)

        self.treeStudentLog.heading("#0", text="Student")
        self.treeStudentLog.column("#0", minwidth=180) 

        self.treeStudentLog.heading("type", text="Log Type")
        self.treeStudentLog.column("type", minwidth=160)           

        self.treeStudentLog.heading("points", text="Points")
        self.treeStudentLog.column("points", minwidth=60)

        self.treeStudentLog.heading("notes", text="Teacher Comments")

        #populate the student log
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM studentlogs ORDER BY logID DESC LIMIT 100")
        allLogs = cursor.fetchall()

        noteLength = 0

        for log in allLogs:
            logNotes = log[3]
            print(type(logNotes))
            try:
                if len(logNotes) > noteLength:
                    noteLength = len(logNotes)
            except:
                noteLength = noteLength

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = ?", (log[2],))
            studentDetails = cursor.fetchone()

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logtypes WHERE typeID = ?", (log[1],))
            logTypeDetails = cursor.fetchone()

            logDesc = logTypeDetails[2]
            logValue = logTypeDetails[1]

            studentName = studentDetails[1] + " " + studentDetails[2]
            self.treeStudentLog.insert('', 'end', text=studentName, values=(logDesc, logValue, logNotes))

        self.treeStudentLog.column("notes", minwidth=noteLength * 8)


        self.treeStudentLog.place(x=10, y=240, width=812)
```

---

Edit: Code I'm using to define a font:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

treeFont = font(self.mainWindow, "Calibri", "12")
```

Where self.mainWindow is the current Top level window (Not the root, but I've tried that too). I've also tried tk.font(blah) to the same effect.

I end up getting a TypeError "module" object is not callable

Comment: why do you say "[font.measure()] doesn't seem applicable for python 3.x"? It's just as functional in 3.x as it is in 2.x

Comment: I can't even manage to define a font in Python 3.3.2. see OP for code I'm using.

Comment: As the error says, `font` (as in `tkinter.font`) is a _module_, not an object. The class you need to instantiate is `font.Font`: `treefont = font.Font(...)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that! I was being a derp.